# could I set the digits when using function map to round in julia?

Tags: julia

In julia, we can use function map to round, for instance,

```
map(round, [1.00211111, 3.444444])
```

Then, the output is
2-element Vector{Float64}:
1.0
3.0

I want to save 3 digits. So I try this:

```
map(round(digits=3), [1.00211111, 3.444444])
```

But it generated errors. How can I do if I want to save 3 digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this scenario just use broadcasting:

```
julia> round.([1.00211111, 3.444444], digits=3)
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.002
 3.444
```

However, if you want to use `map`, you can provide a lambda as an argument:

```
julia> map(x -> round(x, digits=3), [1.00211111, 3.444444])
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.002
 3.444
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I prefer the latter because this idea can be used in python.